# Vuetify v-autocomplete v-text showing the full object instead of text only

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

Vuetify v-autocomplete v-text showing the full object instead of text only.

[image]

here is the code.

```
  data() {
    return {
      people: [
        { name: "test1", value: 1 },
        { name: "test2", value: 2 },
      ]
    };
  },
```

component

```
 <v-autocomplete
   v-model="friends"
   :disabled="isUpdating"
   :items="people"
   item-text="name"
   item-value="id"
   @change="changed"
   filled
   chips
   color="blue-grey lighten-2"
   label="Participants"
   multiple
>
```

Any help? thanks in advance.

Comment: please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  I copied your code into a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-snow-0q2ies?file=/src/App.vue) and did not have any issues.

Comment: Your code should work fine. I did not see any issue in your code. Here is the working fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/3ksthb5c/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the information provided, there doesn't appear to be anything wrong with what you have. However, if you're using v-autocomplete's slot for `#item` inside your v-autocomplete tab, then that could potentially be the source of the issue.

Having a block like this inside your v-autocomplete component would result in the issue you described:

```html
<v-autocomplete ...>
  <template v-slot:item="data">
    {{ data }}
  </template>
</v-autocomplete>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. When working with a slot, then it is required to make changes in the slot template. I was mistaken that I was focusing on v-text attribute while need for a change in templat. thank you for point my attention.

Answer (score 0):

Your code could work well, please double check with the demo:

https://codesandbox.io/s/vuetify-example-sandbox-forked-9ys2tw?file=/src/components/TestComponent.vue

you can also try another option like:

**vuetify 2:**

change item-text to:

```
:item-text="item => item.name"
```

**vuetify 3:**

change item-text to:

```
:item-title="item => item.name"
```

Comment: This is awesome, but it should :item-text="..."

Comment: @ChristopherSchönfeldt you're right :), the answer has been updated now.

Comment: v-autocomplete api not said item-text... https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-autocomplete/#props

How to fix this in vuetify 3? :item-text not working

Comment: @Fabio in vuetify 3, you can :item-title instead
https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/autocompletes/#caveats